# Range of an equation

Tags: inequality

I am trying to find the range of:
$\Large\frac{4 - {\frac {4 + a^2}{a}}}{\frac {1}{2} - \frac {1}{a}}$

So, we have: 
$a \ne 0$

$\frac {1}{2} - \frac {1}{a} \ne 0 $,
$-\frac {1}{a} \ne -\frac {1}{2}$, $\frac {1}{a} \ne \frac {1}{2}$

I am not sure how to solve the last inequality. Thank you in advance!

Comment: $ a \neq 2$, surely?

Comment: @bounceback, is this a question for me?

Comment: I would first simplify the expression into a non-rational form. Then find the domain. And then "transform" the domain to the range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify it and you get $-2(a-2)=4-2a$. With $a \neq 0 \implies 4-2a \neq 4$, and for $a \neq 2 \implies 4-2a \neq 0$. Thus the **range** is $(-\infty, 0)\cup (0,4)\cup (4,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to $$\frac{-\frac{(a-2)^2}{a}}{\frac{a-2}{2a}}$$